# Preserve types in Stripe Plan metadata

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm creating a [`Plan`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans/object) using [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) to which I attach some fields as [`metadata`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans/object#plan_object-metadata).

It seems that Stripe always converts metadata values to `String`s. I'd like to *preserve* the types.

I create a plans like so:

```js
const basic = await stripe.plans.create({
  product: product.id,
  nickname: 'Foo Plan',
  amount: 1000,
  metadata: {
    foo: true, // Boolean
    bar: 10 // Number
  }
})
```

However, when fetching back that `Plan` the metadata field looks like this:

```js
metadata: {
  foo: "true", // String
  bar: "10" // String
}
```

One solution is to store the metadata as a single JSON and parse back but I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually went with storing a JSON, then parsing back like so:

```js
const basic = await stripe.plans.create({
  product: product.id,
  nickname: 'Foo Plan',
  amount: 1000,
  metadata: {
    restrictions: JSON.stringify({
      foo: true,
      bar: 10
    })
  }
})

const getPlan = planId => stripe.plans.retrieve(planId)
  .then(data => Object.assign(data, {
    metadata: JSON.parse(data.metadata.restrictions)
  }))

const plan = await getPlan('id-foo-plan')
console.log(plan.metadata)
```

Just FYI though, from https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata:

> You can specify up to 50 keys, with key names up to 40 characters long and values up to 500 characters long

Answer (score 0):

`metadata` is always a dictionary of string key and string value.

I'd avoid storing the metadata as a single JSON string because there is a max length of the metadata value of 500 char, and often storing JSON in the value field results in errors related to exceeding this limit.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata